# Unable to use infinite scroll using Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, infinite-scroll

Here I m getting data I applied the infinite scrolling but  the items didn't show on my scroll page below is my code:

**.html**

```
     <ion-list 
*ngFor="let infi of IfoData;"  (click)="Item(infi.Id)"   >
        <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">

       <ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    <ion-item>

          <div >

            <p>{{infi.Cost}}</p>

          </div>

        </ion-item>

    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
     </ion-infinite-scroll>
      </ion-list>
```

**.js**

```
        doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
        console.log('Begin async operation');

        setTimeout(() => {
          for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.IfoData.push( this.IfoData.length );
          }

          console.log('Async operation has ended');
          infiniteScroll.complete();
        }, 500);
      }
```

After implementing this code I am just getting empty screen the data is not showing in the template and without implementing this infinite scroll it is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite scroll component must comes last element in ion-content. You should try like this

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item class="itm" *ngFor="let i of IData;"  (click)="goItem(i.Id,i.Name)">
      <ion-avatar item-start role="img">
        <img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+i.Image" style="width: 110px;">
      </ion-avatar>

      <div class="item-inner">
        <h2 class="_nme">{{i.Name}}</h2>
        <p class="_price">{{i.Cost}}</p>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
      </div>

    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

ion-infinite-scroll-content is to change the default spinner and add text in infinite scroll

Refer the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) for details

Comment: Please check my updated question even though i don't have the list it is displaying list

Answer (score 0):

put infinite scroll at the last in ion-content

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

and in your ts file
 doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

```
    setTimeout(() => {
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.iData.push( this.iData.length );
  }

  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  infiniteScroll.complete();
}, 500);
```

Comment: I hope that it could work for sure as it is working in my code correctly@Devpop

Comment: Please check my updated question even though i  dont have the list it is displaying list

Comment: Can u explain in detail what you want.....I am able to get the exact point!!!@Devpop